# Why is my MySQL Database on AWS not accessible?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I cannot reach my MySQL Database instance I created on AWS.
What I tried was to set the public access of the Database to "Publicly accessible" here:

[image]

Also I tried to set Inbound/Outbound rules for the MySQL port here:
[image]
[image]

Honestly I think using "All" ports would include 3306 too. Anyways, I tried it this way because yet it didn't work. I cannot connect to the database via MySQL Workbench, nor can I use a ping request on the given endpoint.

I would be glad if someone here has an idea what I could try else.

Comment: Have you deployed it in a public subnet or maybe private one?

Comment: what does mean "can't connect"? Time out? refused? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work if you have deployed it in a private subnet which has no internet access.

Another possibility is that there is ACLs that is stopping the traffic. Security group only touch the RDS instance, the ACLs control traffic in the entire subnet.

Comment: My ACL configuration was wrong. After adding a rule for all TCP connections, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: It proved ACL is the reason, but I strongly recommend against opening all TCP in your ACL to your Database. Database should be protected and you should restrict access to the bare minimum of what you need. Otherwise you and putting data security at risk.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dev AWS tutorial that creates a web application that stores data in MySQL running on the cloud. It will show you how to setup the database and the inbound rules. Once you do, you can store data or query data from MySQL. Likewise, you can use MySQL Workbench to interact with MySQL on the cloud.

[AWS RDS Tutorial](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_rds_item_tracker)